# Processor overheats and system slows right down

Tags: 20.04, overheating

Had 18.10-no problem. Upgraded to LTS 20.4.1.Toshiba Satellite laptop. Since then the processor overheats and system slows right down. Checked System Monitor and there is nothing obvious happening, but CPU4 is running at 100% a lot of the time. Please suggest way forward for troubleshooting. TIA

Comment: Good idea - I'll give it a try and let you know how it works out.